# Time evolution of beam splitter Hamiltonian (via $e^{-i H t}$)

Tags: quantum-optics

As asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438723/is-the-beam-splitter-transformation-related-to-hamiltonian), the beam splitter Hamiltonian has the form $\hat{H}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2}+\hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{1}\right)$.

I would like to construct the standard quantum optics "unitary beam splitter operator" from this Hamiltonian using the time evolution operator $e^{-i Ht}$. In this case I get:

$\hat{U}=\exp \left[-\frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2}+\hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{1}\right)\right]$.

How do I split up this exponential?

At first glance it seems like I can use the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Emehen/760/ProblemSets/BCH.pdf) (BCH) formula:

$$e^{A} e^{B}=e^{A+B+[A, B] / 2}$$

But this only works if [A, B] = c, where c is a constant. In my case, $A = -\frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2}$ and  $B = -\frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger}$, and their commutation is nonzero (see calculation at end).

Any ideas how I can proceed?

Just to show my calculation that $[A, B] \neq c$:

$$ \frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} \frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger}- \frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger}\frac{i  t}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2}$$

$$ \frac{t^2}{2}\left(-\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger}+ \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} \right)$$

$$ \frac{t^2}{2}\left(-\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}  \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger}+ \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} \right)$$

$$ \frac{t^2}{2}\left(\hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} -\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}  \hat{a}_{1} \hat{a}_{2} \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \right)$$

$$ [a, a^\dagger ] = 1$$
$$ a a^\dagger- a^\dagger a = 1$$
$$ a a^\dagger = 1 + a^\dagger a$$
$$ a_2 a_2^\dagger = 1 + a_2^\dagger a_2$$
$$ a_1 a_1^\dagger = 1 + a_1^\dagger a_1$$

$$ \frac{t^2}{2}\left(\left(1 + a_1^\dagger a_1 \right) \hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} -\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}  \hat{a}_{1} \left(1 + a_2^\dagger a_2 \right) \right)$$

$$ \frac{t^2}{2}\left(\hat{a}_{2}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{2} -\hat{a}_{1}^{\dagger}  \hat{a}_{1}  \right)$$

Comment: Life would definitely be much easier in the Heisenberg picture. (Probably even to derive $U$ in the Heisenberg picture and then map it back.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, yeah I've seen a solution you provided to a similar problem that did that.  I am curious to see if it's possible to go in this direction, and if it was obvious how to do it without going to the Heisenberg picture.

Comment: One option that seems to work is that if you have exactly 1 photon, you can work out your coefficients by representing the exponential matrix $e^{-i H t}$ as a Taylor series, and you end up with something like $cos(t/ \hbar)|0,1\rangle + i sin(t/ \hbar)|1,0\rangle$.

Comment: Well, if you like pain, I'm sure it is possible to do it without using the Heisenberg picture. In essence, there's only so much the commutators in the exponential can do. But I'd guess it is more painful and not much more insightful. (Note that there is a generalization of BCH to cases where the commutator is not constant: It is an infinite sequence of commutators you get ... )

Comment: Note that working with one photon seems like going half-way to the Heisenberg picture: It seems you can use some similar ideas, but get a much weaker result.

Comment: @StevenSagona When you say you want to "construct" $U$, what kind of expression for $U$ are you hoping for? The question says "split up this exponential," but what does that mean? (I'm not saying it's meaningless, I'm saying that it has lots of different possible meanings and I don't know which one is desired.)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly, I'm looking to see if I can reduce this to the [standard unitary beam splitter operator](https://pages.uoregon.edu/svanenk/solutions/NotesBS.pdf).

Comment: @StevenSagona Maybe my reading comprehension skills are failing me, but I didn't find a unitary operator in the linked document. I saw some unitary transformations applied to specific states, but not a state-independent unitary operator. The question seems to be asking for a specific way of writing the latter. Does the linked document show an example of how you want $U$ to be expressed?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly, I was just pointing to how two modes will change on a beam splitter, like $b^\dagger = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(a_1 + a_2^\dagger)$ I think it's a fair point that this only works for single photons.

Comment: @StevenSagona The formula you give is in the Heisenberg picture (and applies independent of the number of photons), and deriving it by starting from the Heisenberg equation for the operators is immediate. Does the reference you quote give a form of U in the Schroedinger picture? Otherwise, if you want to derive the form you quote, start from $\dot a = i[H,a]$ - this will be immediate. There's good reason people work in this representation.